# Debate on definition of Critical point and local / absolute extremas

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, definition, proof-explanation, stationary-point

So my question is:

1. ***Is a global extremum necessarily a also local extremum?***

I think the answer is **no** if you define that f has a local max at c if
f(c) ≥ f(x) for all x near c, even for those x not in the domain, then an endpoint which is a global maximum of the domain is not a local maximum since we can find points in a neighborhood of c such that f(c) < f(x) even if that x is not in the domain. It would be also local if we defined local max as f(c) ≥ f(x) for all x of the domain near c.

2. ***Can a stationary point be something OTHER than a local extrema or saddle point?***

I had the 2) on an exam and the correct answer was TRUE. the above definition for local extremum explains why we could have a extremum on an endpoint that is global but not local. But here I think the trick is with the definition of stationary point.
In my class we distinguish stationary points (where the gradient is 0) and critical points (where the gradient does not exist.)
My reasoning is this: A critical point can be a point where the gradiant is not defined i.e an endpoint. And an endpoint can be an absolute extrema but cannot be a local extrema. Thus the statement is true because a stationary point also could be global extremum rather than a local extremum or saddle point.

**CONTEXT**:

I had a discussion with a friend:

He told me that a stationary point is not necessarily a point of the function that is differentiable.

I thought that a to be a stationary point that point must cancel the gradient. But he told me that 
**that was true only if we know that the function is differentiable at that point**.

And a teacher told him that

> if it is not mentioned that f is differentiable then a stationary
>   point is not always a local min, local max or saddle.

That really confused me because **I thought stationary point where only defined on functions where the gradient exists and is equal to 0** at that point.

EDIT:
From wikipedia: "If the function is smooth, or, at least twice continuously differentiable, a critical point may be either a local maximum, a local minimum or a saddle point."
Does this imply that the function being smooth is a necessity thus implying that a critical point can be other than an extremum or saddle point?
So what happens if the function is not smooth?

Comment: A function doesn't have to be differentiable at its extrema. For example, consider $f(x) = \vert x \vert$. However, I believe the most common convention is to define a stationary point to be one where the derivative exists and is zero.

Comment: so the statement: "a stationary point of a function f(x,y) is always a local max, local min or a saddle point" would be false because it could also be a global min max??

Comment: Global maxes/mins are also local maxes/mins.

Comment: Even if the point is an endpoint? is it still a local max/min ?

Comment: The endpoints can be critical points, but they are definitely local maxes/mins. This definition relies on the fact that the function is undefined before/after the endpoint.

Comment: For example, the "start" of the function is greater than all the undefined values that come before it, and similarly, the "end" is greater that all the undefined value that come after it. I believe some definitions use this property to argue the endpoints have no slope, but others say that there has to be a change from positive to negative derivative (or vice versa), which the endpoints don't have.

Comment: This is more or less a matter of convention and mathematical history.

Comment: What is the definition of "stationary point" given by the textbook or the professor?  Is this in the context of constraints and Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: He said a stationary point is a point on a differentiable function where the gradient = 0. The context is multivariable extremas.

Comment: @TobyMak so these endpoints are not considered stationary points, then when is the statement that a stationary point of any function must be an extremum or saddle false?

Comment: It is possible to have a critical point on a manifold where the gradient of the function does not vanish in the embedding space.  Take the simple "manifold" defined by a differentiable curve on a smooth surface in 3-space where there is some  scalar function $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$  such as temperature.  So when you drive your car along a mountain road, there is some point where the temperature becomes a maximum or minimum, but the 3-space gradient doesn't vanish.

Comment: @TobyMak so when you say
"The endpoints can be critical points, but they are definitely local maxes/mins." Does that mean that a global max is always also a local max?

Comment: Critical points don't have to be global maxes/mins, it is just a term for when the gradient is zero. Therefore, a global max that is the absolute maximum of a function is a local max that is the maximum in a given range, which just is $]- \infty, \infty[$ in this case. Note that this cannot be reversed - a local max is not always a global max.